# Выражение Assert при тестировании метода, который обновляет объект через сторонний сервис

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development, mocking, nsubstitute

### Код

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDto
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;

    public CustomerService(IGenericRepository<Customer> customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public CustomerDto Add(CustomerDto dto)
    {
        //Validation
        if (dto == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dto));
        }
        var validContext = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(dto);
        Validator.ValidateObject(dto, validContext);

        //Mapping by AutoMapper
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>());
        var entity = Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customer>(dto);            

        _customerRepository.Insert(entity);
        _customerRepository.Save();

        dto.Id = entity.Id;

        return dto;
    }
}
```

---

### Юнит-тестирование CustomerService.Add()

Необходимо создать юнит-тест для метода `Add()`. *Изначально, вообще была попытка реализовать этот метод через TDD, т.е. сначала создать для него юнит-тест и только затем имлемантацию.* Но я не смог этого сделать так как не разобрался за что конкретно отвечает этот метод и **надо ли вообще писать для него тест**.

Но два юнит-теста я сделал и вот как все это выглядит:

```
[TestClass]
public class Customer_Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Use NSubstitude for mocking
        var mockRepository = Substitute.For<IGenericRepository<Customer>>();

        //Act
        var service = new CustomerService(mockRepository);
        var dto = new CustomerDto
        {
            Surname = "Shakhabov",
            Name = "Adam"
        };
        var addedDto = service.Add(dto);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(addedDto);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
    public void Add_TestException()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockRepository = Substitute.For<IGenericRepository<Customer>>();

        //Act
        var service = new CustomerService(mockRepository);
        var dto = new CustomerDto
        {
            Surname = "Shakhabov",                
        };
        var addedDto = service.Add(dto);

        //Assert
        //expectedException ValidationException
    }
}
```

Вот *что* (цель) должен сделать метод: Добавить в базу данных `объект` на основе полученного `DTO-объекта` и затем обратно вернуть этот `DTO-объект`, но уже **с обновленным полем `Id`, значение для которого сформировала СУБД**.

Вот *как* (задачи) делает это метод:

1. Получив DTO-объект, сразу верифицирует его;
2. Используя библиотеку AutoMapper, проецирует DTO на сущность, которая в свою очередь создается с нуля;
3. Используя объект-репозиторий, добавляет сущность в контекст.
4. Сохраняет контекст в результате чего источник данных (СУБД)
   инициализирует поле Id у сущности (entity);
5. Инициализирует поле dto.Id полем entity.Id и возвращает DTO.

---

### Вопрос

Правильно ли были сформулированы требования для метода `Add()` и соответственно построены юнит-тесты на их основе? Какие тесты (выражения `Assert`) создаются для методов с подобной логикой, где целью является инициализировать свойство `DTO-объекта` значением, получаемое сторонним сервисом (в данном случаи объект-репозиторий)?

Comment: @DenisBubnov, на счет `dto.Id = dto.Id`. Да, это была опечатка. Обновил.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, все замечания учтены, но я так и не понял как проверить получаемый `Id`, ведь он происходит как бы из ни "откуда". Его (Id) не сервис и не репозиторий делает, а контекст. Без кода трудно понять, что ты предлагаешь говоря: _конвертацию из DTO в сущность БД перенести внутрь DTO_

Comment: Да конечно, хорошо бы чтобы был ответ с кодом, а так: у меня используется Database first, поэтому сущности мне не подвластны, а `CustomerDto.ToCustomer()` увидеть на деле хотелось бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим в метод `Add`. Что делает метод добавления? Добавляет новую сущность в БД и присваивает ей уникальный идентификатор.

С точки зрения возвращаемого значения - нужно вернуть только идентификатор, так как весь объект остался без изменений. Когда DTO приходит в метод добавления - идентификатор нулевой, то есть не заполнен. Когда сущьность (entity) будет добавлена в БД, ей будет присвоен новый уникальный идентифкатор. Так как используется тип данных `int`, то иднетификатор обязательно будет положительным (больше нуля) и уникален.

Конвертацию из DTO в объект сущности БД перенести внутрь DTO или добавить конструктор в сущность БД, который примет в качестве параметра DTO-шку. Про конвертацию подробнее: либо в объекте `Customer` сделать конструктор, который будет принимать объект типа `CustomerDto`, где внутри произвести присвоение полей с помощью AutoMapper, либо в `CustomerDto` сделать метод `ToCustomer()`, внутри которого создастся объект `Customer` и будут присвоены поля, который вернет объект типа `Customer`. Думаю, что с точки зрения логики, метод `Add` не должен делать эту конвертацию, так как его задача взять объект, добавить его и на основании результата уже будем знать, прошло ли все успешно.

Пример кода метода `ToCustomer()` в классе `CustomerDto`, для этого возможно понадобится подключить `using` для типа `Customer` и для `AutoMapper`, но это не беда, вот что я имел в виду:

```
public Customer ToCustomer()
{
    //Mapping by AutoMapper
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>());
    var entity = Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customer>(dto); 
    return entity;
}
```

По-хорошему и валидацию сделать бы более компактной и красивой, но это уже на ваше усмотрение. Еще один совет, инкапсулируйте в репозитрорий методы `Insert` и `Save` внутрь одного метода, который выполнит это (назовите его `Create` или `Add`). Ну и навесьте `try...catch` внутри метода, к примеру, если что-то пошло не так и упало исключение - тогда метод вернул `-1`, а в тестах вы уже будете знать, что если меньше нуля - то тест не прошел.

Касаемо тестов, у вас два сценария:

- метод отработал успешно и без исключения - нужно проверить, что идентификатор не нулевой (больше нуля);
- пробуем подсунуть некорректные данные, которые вызовут исключение.

Соответственно, тестовый метод, проверяющий успешную работу должен проверить, что идентификатор не нулевой. Пример проверки: [C# unit test, how to test greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4138171/5275890) Там где ожидается исключение - не должно быть `Assert` проверок.

Касаемо TDD - это сложная практика, которая нарабатывается с опытом. Проще начать с написания простых классов через TDD, а потом уже переходить к более сложным сценариям. Чтобы писать через TDD, нужно иметь четкое представление того, как должна работать та или иная функциональность, которую вы хотите реализовать с ее помощью.

А еще, сейчас я занимаюсь приведением большого проекта в порядок с помощью одного вспомогательного компонента под названием [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop), так вот он не рекомендует использовать знак нижнего подчеркивания в именовании свойств, полей, параметров, переменных и прочего. Ну это так, к слову. Надеюсь, что мои советы и пояснения достаточно ясны и не вызовут противоречий.

Comment: Про StyleCop был не в курсе. А _нижнее подчеркивание_, так это ReSharper просит меня это делать

Comment: @adamshakhabov, да это не обязательно, я вот к примеру привык приватные поля писать с нижнего подчеркивания, а тут бац - StyleCop говорит, что не стоит так делать... Мистика :)